# Get the indexes of elements in a nested list

Tags: python

I have a nested list

```
elements = [['A'],['B','C'],['D','E','F']]
```

and I have list of indexes

```
index= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want to group by the indexes meaning the output would look like this:

```
out = [[1],[2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Comment: and what is your first attempt to solve this?

Comment: so far, Im not able to have a code to solve it

Answer (score 0):

You can slice (with [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)) relying on the length of each sublist:

```
from itertools import islice

vals = [['A'], ['B','C'], ['D','E','F']]
indices = iter([1,2,3,4,5,6])
slices = [list(islice(indices, len(sub_l))) for sub_l in vals]
print(slices)
```

---

```
[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to use `iter` to make index an iterable, then loop through the elements list and get the `next` element in the iterable.

```
iter_index = iter(index)

result = [[next(iter_index) for _ in group] for group in elements]
```

---

```
[[1], [2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in a comprehension using an internal iterator:

```
result = [ [next(i) for _ in e] for i in [iter(index)] for e in elements ]

print(result)

[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Alternatively, you could compute the starting position of each sub-list in the index list and use that in a comprehension to get the corresponding subset of indexes:

```
startPos = [0]
startPos.extend(len(e)+startPos[-1] for e in elements)
result  = [ index[p:p+len(e)] for p,e in zip(startPos,elements) ] 

print(result)
# [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Using the same logic but based on the ending positions, you could use accumulate from itertools to compute the positions:

```
from itertools import accumulate

endPos = accumulate(map(len,elements))
result = [index[p-len(e):p] for p,e in zip(endPos,elements)]

print(result)
# [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

If it's ok to "destroy" the content of the index list in the process, you could write it like this:

```
result = [[index.pop(0) for _ in e] for e in elements]

print(result)
# [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```